# Create tf_record for selected class_ids on COCO Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tfrecord, mscoco

I have the full COCO 2017 Dataset (Train,Test,Val) and i want to create tf_record files out of it.
But not for all classes, but rather for only some selected ones.
Therefore I have a label_map containing all classes i want to include in the tf_records in the following tf format:

```
item {
  name: "/m/01g317"
  id: 1
  display_name: "person"
}
item {
  name: "/m/0199g"
  id: 2
  display_name: "bicycle"
}
```

The standard script for creating the complete tf_record for all classes is this:

```
def create_tf_example(image,
                      annotations_list,
                      image_dir,
                      category_index,
                      include_masks=False):
  """Converts image and annotations to a tf.Example proto.

  Args:
    image: dict with keys:
      [u'license', u'file_name', u'coco_url', u'height', u'width',
      u'date_captured', u'flickr_url', u'id']
    annotations_list:
      list of dicts with keys:
      [u'segmentation', u'area', u'iscrowd', u'image_id',
      u'bbox', u'category_id', u'id']
      Notice that bounding box coordinates in the official COCO dataset are
      given as [x, y, width, height] tuples using absolute coordinates where
      x, y represent the top-left (0-indexed) corner.  This function converts
      to the format expected by the Tensorflow Object Detection API (which is
      which is [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] with coordinates normalized relative
      to image size).
    image_dir: directory containing the image files.
    category_index: a dict containing COCO category information keyed
      by the 'id' field of each category.  See the
      label_map_util.create_category_index function.
    include_masks: Whether to include instance segmentations masks
      (PNG encoded) in the result. default: False.
  Returns:
    example: The converted tf.Example
    num_annotations_skipped: Number of (invalid) annotations that were ignored.

  Raises:
    ValueError: if the image pointed to by data['filename'] is not a valid JPEG
  """
  image_height = image['height']
  image_width = image['width']
  filename = image['file_name']
  image_id = image['id']

  full_path = os.path.join(image_dir, filename)
  with tf.gfile.GFile(full_path, 'rb') as fid:
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
  image = PIL.Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
  key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_jpg).hexdigest()

  xmin = []
  xmax = []
  ymin = []
  ymax = []
  is_crowd = []
  category_names = []
  category_ids = []
  area = []
  encoded_mask_png = []
  num_annotations_skipped = 0
  for object_annotations in annotations_list:
    (x, y, width, height) = tuple(object_annotations['bbox'])
    if width <= 0 or height <= 0:
      num_annotations_skipped += 1
      continue
    if x + width > image_width or y + height > image_height:
      num_annotations_skipped += 1
      continue
    xmin.append(float(x) / image_width)
    xmax.append(float(x + width) / image_width)
    ymin.append(float(y) / image_height)
    ymax.append(float(y + height) / image_height)
    is_crowd.append(object_annotations['iscrowd'])
    category_id = int(object_annotations['category_id'])
    category_ids.append(category_id)
    category_names.append(category_index[category_id]['name'].encode('utf8'))
    area.append(object_annotations['area'])

    if include_masks:
      run_len_encoding = mask.frPyObjects(object_annotations['segmentation'],
                                          image_height, image_width)
      binary_mask = mask.decode(run_len_encoding)
      if not object_annotations['iscrowd']:
        binary_mask = np.amax(binary_mask, axis=2)
      pil_image = PIL.Image.fromarray(binary_mask)
      output_io = io.BytesIO()
      pil_image.save(output_io, format='PNG')
      encoded_mask_png.append(output_io.getvalue())
  feature_dict = {
      'image/height':
          dataset_util.int64_feature(image_height),
      'image/width':
          dataset_util.int64_feature(image_width),
      'image/filename':
          dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf8')),
      'image/source_id':
          dataset_util.bytes_feature(str(image_id).encode('utf8')),
      'image/key/sha256':
          dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
      'image/encoded':
          dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
      'image/format':
          dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin':
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmin),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax':
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmax),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin':
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymin),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax':
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymax),
      'image/object/class/label':
          dataset_util.int64_list_feature(category_ids),
      'image/object/is_crowd':
          dataset_util.int64_list_feature(is_crowd),
      'image/object/area':
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(area),
  }
  if include_masks:
    feature_dict['image/object/mask'] = (
        dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(encoded_mask_png))
  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
  return key, example, num_annotations_skipped


def _create_tf_record_from_coco_annotations(
    annotations_file, image_dir, output_path, include_masks):
  """Loads COCO annotation json files and converts to tf.Record format.

  Args:
    annotations_file: JSON file containing bounding box annotations.
    image_dir: Directory containing the image files.
    output_path: Path to output tf.Record file.
    include_masks: Whether to include instance segmentations masks
      (PNG encoded) in the result. default: False.
  """
  with tf.gfile.GFile(annotations_file, 'r') as fid:
    groundtruth_data = json.load(fid)
    images = groundtruth_data['images']
    category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(
        groundtruth_data['categories'])

    annotations_index = {}
    if 'annotations' in groundtruth_data:
      tf.logging.info(
          'Found groundtruth annotations. Building annotations index.')
      for annotation in groundtruth_data['annotations']:
        image_id = annotation['image_id']
        if image_id not in annotations_index:
          annotations_index[image_id] = []
        annotations_index[image_id].append(annotation)
    missing_annotation_count = 0
    for image in images:
      image_id = image['id']
      if image_id not in annotations_index:
        missing_annotation_count += 1
        annotations_index[image_id] = []
    tf.logging.info('%d images are missing annotations.',
                    missing_annotation_count)

    tf.logging.info('writing to output path: %s', output_path)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_path)
    total_num_annotations_skipped = 0
    for idx, image in enumerate(images):
      if idx % 100 == 0:
        tf.logging.info('On image %d of %d', idx, len(images))
      annotations_list = annotations_index[image['id']]
      _, tf_example, num_annotations_skipped = create_tf_example(
          image, annotations_list, image_dir, category_index, include_masks)
      total_num_annotations_skipped += num_annotations_skipped
      writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    tf.logging.info('Finished writing, skipped %d annotations.',
                    total_num_annotations_skipped)
```

i tried to load my custom label map as category index with the label_map_util but it gives me key errors i dont know how to solve.

Has anybody an idea how to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps

1. I [followed this link to](https://github.com/CasiaFan/Dataset_to_VOC_converter) generate class wise xmls based on the coco json annotations.
2. this will create separate folders for each class and we can select the classes required and club them all together into one folder. This results in a custom dataset of fewer objects but the XML's still contain the objects names which are not required since coco has multiple instances of different classes in same image.
3. then i parsed the xml for only the required objects based on their class names and ids. This left me with few xmls which are only required.
4. Then i used some linux commands to curate the images in the dataset based on XML names. this resulted in a separate folder with the images and annotations that are only needed.
5. then I created csv files using the XMLs which I fed into tf record script to generate train.record and test.record which I fed into training.

Everything worked out fine except the training stopped in the middle saying "premature end of Jpeg". I tried restarting the training from previous check point but the training again stops after certain number of steps. But the training loss seem to be converging while the training is going on. I verified the record files by their size. the tf_record file and the image folder has approximately the same size. I am now stuck at figuring this out.

Any further help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unless this being a very permanent link (say by MS), do mention the steps mentioned out there **within** the answer, it enables information preserving even if the link goes dead.

Comment: This method worked out for me. The error for premature end of jpg is because the dataset got corrupted when I downloaded for some reason. This got fixed when I re downloaded the dataset. I currently reduced the coco dataset for 10 objects/classes. Thanks